# google maps loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website (which uses `jquery bbq`) where an ajax request is fired off and a `div` somewhere in the body is replaced when the response is received. Something along the lines of:

```
var mainContent = $('#main_content');
if ( cache[ url ] ) {
        mainContent.fadeOut(duration, function() {
            mainContent.html(cache[ url ]);
            mainContent.fadeIn(duration, function() {
                $(document).trigger("ajax_loaded");
            });
        });

    } else {

        mainContent.fadeOut(duration, function() {

            var postAjaxCallback = function() {
                cache[ url ] = mainContent.html();
                $(document).trigger("ajax_loaded");
            };

            $('#loading').fadeIn(duration, do_ajax(url, duration, postAjaxCallback));
        } );

    }

function do_ajax(linkVal, duration, callback) {

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: linkVal,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(page){
        var mainContent = $('#main_content');
        mainContent.stop(true, true);

        if(parseInt(page)!=0)  
        {
            mainContent.html(page);
            $('#loading').fadeOut(duration, function() {
                mainContent.fadeIn(duration, callback);                 
            } );
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Now on the whole this works great. The main page is something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
       ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_content");
           <p>Hello world!</p>
        </div>
    /body>
</html>
```

and the ajax return for `#page2` is something like

```
<p>Hello to a different world!</p>
```

On `#page3` it gets a bit more complicated. The ajax returned is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    streetViewControlOptions: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.737792, 49.878273),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript();

$(document).bind("ajax_loaded", function() {
        console.log("map resize called");
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
</script>
```

Now the first time `#page3` is loaded, everything works fine, the console log fires and the map is resized (needs to be resized because of the grey area problem). Now what I *want* to happen is that all other pages continue to load normally (either via the ajax calls or from the cache), and that when `#page3` is navigated to again (i.e. the `#("main_content")` is set from the cache, that the resize event fires again. I guess in the simplest terms, I am trying to create an event that I trigger after each ajax page is loaded and I can have a custom `$(document).bind("ajax_loaded", function() {});` on each ajax retrieved page that can do any post processing I need.
The behaviour currently exhibited is that nothing happens until I load `#page3` (and as I mentioned the map is resized and everything is gravy). After that, each page load triggers the bound function and prints to the console (reasonable I guess since I have bound it to `$(document)`, is there something better to do to make it unique to each page?) However, the real pain is that when I try to reload `#page3`, the maps loads but is not resized (the console still prints) so I have grey areas on the map.
Can anyone help me with my limited javascript experience to get the workflow right. To reiterate:

- Each ajax load (or load from cache) will trigger some event
- Within each ajax page (`#page1`, `#page2` etc.) there will be a function that is triggered from the above step that can do setup unique to each ajax page.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**
I have tried using the following:

```
mainContent.find("script").each(function(i) {
    eval($(this).text());
});
```

instead of triggering the `ajax_loaded` event but to no avail. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything gets screwed, when the Google Maps API is added second time (reload of `#page3`. It causes some error and the rest of the script probably stops working. Try to wrap the loading of Google Maps API into condition `if (typeof google === 'undefined') { ...`.

But to be honest, the whole concept might need some refactoring :).